# munmap return an error

Tags: ios, mmap, memory-mapped-files

Hi I'm using mmap to map a file (150 mb) on ios.
the mmap works great, I'm able to get the data from start to end but when I want to dealloc it, I can't, each time I get -1 with a errno 3 no such process :

what I'am doing wrong ?

Exemple :

```
FILE* mappedFile;
int fd = fileno(mappedFile);

ftruncate(fd, _size);

void* mapMem = mmap(
        (size_t)_size,
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_FILE | MAP_SHARED,
        fd,
        0
); 

// Do some stuffs

munmap(mapMem , _size);
```

thank for all

Comment: Aren't you meant to use `_size`?

Comment: sorry bad copy and paste. I edited the code